# Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dialogflow-es

Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: AGENT_ID and intentId: INTENT_ID.

Here, I have two intents named as service intent and pin intent.
In service intent i used to training phrase like "show me savings account balance". Then it will go the next intent that is pin intent. After providing pin above mentioned error occured.

I have tried following code block.

here is my service intent code

```
app.intent('askService', (conv, params) => {

 let pinRequired = false;

 if (pinRequired) {

  conv.user.storage.pin_prompt_count = 0;
  conv.ask('Let’s start with you giving me your PIN.');
  deleteContext(conv);
  conv.contexts.delete('ask-service-context');
  conv.contexts.set('account-pin-context', 5);

  return;
 }
});
```

here is my pin intent code

```
app.intent('askPin', (conv, params) => {

  var member = services.getMemberDetails(memberId, params.account_pin);

  return member.then(function (result) {

    if (result) {

     conv.user.storage.pin_prompt_count = 0; 
     conv.contexts.delete('account-pin-context');

     return handleService(conv);
   }
  }).catch(function (err) {
     conv.ask("Invalid Pin. Please try again");
 })
});
```

Here, "show me savings account balance" training phrase is available in service intent. Then it will go for pin entry, after sucessful pin entry it will go to the handleService method.

How i can get rid of this error?

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does your services.getMemberDetails call an external API? If you're using firebase you have to upgrade to the pay as you go option for your function. Firebase doesn't allow external API calls on their free version.

Comment: Yes it is an external API call, and it has been upgraded and billing is configured also. Before billing configuration 'Billing is not configured, please select your plan' error was occuring. But now it is billing configured.